# Is there a solution for Rails Gem Devise to allow a user to have multiple emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm looking for a solution to allow a user on my app to have more than 1 email. This should work similar to Facebook, LinkedIn and Quora. Where an account can have multiple emails, 1 as the primary.

Is there a turn-key solution for devise avaialble? I'm hoping to not have to write this from scratch given it's so common.

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to enable sign-in with those secondary emails too, for any user?

Comment: Yes, a user should only be able to sign in with any of their emails. Also an email should not be able to co-exist, unique emails per accounts across the entire system... Just like how Facebook handles this...

Comment: I'm not aware of an existing solution to this, but if you decide to write it yourself, you might start with this, which is at least similar (multiple possible login values): https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Answer (score 15):

Hm...I'll suggest to create new model, You'll do something like this:

For example model would be`UserEmail`.

```
class UserEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_emails
end
```

and override devise's method to find record in `User` model:

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if email = conditions.delete(:email)
    User.includes(:user_emails).where('user_emails.email = ?', email).first
  else
    super(warden_conditions)
  end
```

Read more about override here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Comment: This will fail (in a potentially insecure way) for other Devise lookups, such as finding a user by their confirmation token or unlock token. See my answer for a fix.

Comment: How do you deal with password recovery? what do I do if i want to let the user choose which email he want the link to be sent to?

Comment: As I know, to reset password user must fill his email in form. And you will deliver message if email exists.

Answer (score 8):

Bob's answer is close but it has a potentially dangerous bug. The `find_first_by_auth_conditions` method should look like this:

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if email = conditions.delete(:email)
    User.includes(:user_emails).where('user_emails.email = ?', email).first
  else
    super(warden_conditions)
  end
end
```

The email check and call to `super` is important, because Devise also uses this method to look up `User`s by `confirmation_token`, `unlock_token`, and `reset_token`. Without the else branch, any calls to this method that don't have an `email` parameter will either fail, or load up a User with a `nil` email.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to create a new model `SecondaryEmail`.
A `User` can `has_many :secondary_emails`, and each `SecondaryEmail` `belongs_to :user`.

You will have to add the validation of uniqueness for each email in `SecondaryEmail`, and further, will have to make sure that no new SecondaryEmail is already a primary email of any User.
Provide the interface, so that a `User` can add his secondary_emails, with those validations.

Next step will be overriding the `SessionController` of **Devise**.
Upon any login procedure, set up your login procedure for `SecondaryEmail.where(:email => params[:email])` whenever an email is not found in User's primary emails. If it exists, authenticate with that user's password, else, user doesn't exist.

This is what I came up with so far. I would really love to know the experts' view and approach in this. :)

Answer (score 3):

I came across this problem awhile ago - and have outlined the solution in [my blog](http://lorefnon.me/2014/09/07/devise-multiple-emails.html) .

The steps are summarized below:

- Email information has to be stored in a additional model, say `Email`. So a `User` has many related `Email` instances.
- We would most likely want to designate one email as the default email which we can use for communication with the user.
- The class method of the `User` class `find_first_by_auth_conditions` is used to find the user for provided credentials - so we will have to override that method to search using the `Email` model.
- We will have to change the default views because they implicitly assume the presence of `email` method of user. Rather than rewriting the views entirely we can use add a proxy accessor for email that delegates to the default email for the user.
- If a user is allowed to have multiple emails - we would also like to provide the user facility to add/remove emails in the account edit page.
- If you need omniauth integration - then the stock implementation of `User.from_omniauth` outlined in the devise wiki will have to be modified to support multiple emails.

My implementation is available [on Github](https://github.com/lorefnon/devise_multi_email_demo).

Answer (score 1):

The answers given here is pretty good, and should solve your problem. To answer your last question, i don't think you will find a gem for this, as it's too simple even though it's pretty common. Just make it from scratch as suggested, it should not be to much work :)

Answer (score 1):

Bob's answer threw a SQL error for me in rails 4.1.5- the below change got it working, per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations:

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if email = conditions.delete(:email)
    User.includes(:user_emails).where(user_emails: {email: email}).first
  else
    super(warden_conditions)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the devise-multi_email gem: https://github.com/allenwq/devise-multi_email

Replace `devise :authenticatable` with `devise :multi_email_authenticatable`, so that your models might look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails

  # Replace :database_authenticatable, with :multi_email_authenticatable
  devise :multi_email_authenticatable, :registerable
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And if you want all the emails to be confirmable and recover your password from anyone of your emails, just

`devise :multi_email_authenticatable, :multi_email_confirmable, :confirmable`