# Does rails devise authentication token for user have to be reset on user logout? How to impelment multiple logins

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, devise

My question is dead simple.

Does authentication token have to be reset on user logout?

Currently I am just developing an iOS application but there's a possibility for web, iPad, and Android applications too. If a single user account has to be able to be logged in to various devices, what is the best solution to achieve this?

I am currently saving user authentication token in NSUserDefaults to send with every request.

If there is just one user account and its authentication token and a user logs out and reset the authentication token, the user won't be able to use the application on other devices such as web, iPad, and Android because the authentication token is no longer valid now.

What is the best way to achieve this login on multiple devices?

**My thoughts**
My one thought is to make a login model that belongs to a user model and make that login model token authenticatable. Then each login can create a login model and destroy that model after logout. I will wait for any other solutions :) gg.

Comment: You can post one more variable platform and pass android iOS etc in this variable. So that each device can have it's own login access token. How about that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As I know, token doesn't reset on logout.
2. I answered similar question several days ago.

[Is there a solution for Rails Gem Devise to allow a user to have multiple emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285077/is-there-a-solution-for-rails-gem-devise-to-allow-a-user-to-have-multiple-emails/16285486#16285486)

In your case you can create for example `UserDevices` model instead of `UserEmails` and override `find_for_token_authentication` in `User` model.

Some help you can find in comments here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/token_authenticatable.rb

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If tokens are not reset on logout, then is is possible to use just User model not UserDevices model, since logout on one device will not affect others?

Comment: You can override logout method to reset token on `UserDevice` model. Anyway, if your user can have multiple devices, I think you should create separate model to handle it.