# How can i allow user to authenticate using email and some other field in devise instead of email and password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise for authentication and i use rails as backend for ios application. I wanted to save the user attributes and it does not have password field in the registration, so i overrided the devise registration controller and made it as required.

Now i wanted to allow the user to be authenticated on the every request, so usually i use `"authenticate_user!"` method in other controllers so it would check the user on every request but it requires password to do so but in my case i now do not have password, so how can i verify the user on every request.

Can i able to override the authenticate_user! method and allow to check email and type(for example) instead of email and password or tell me if there is some other way.

Also please tell me how devise access the authorization header and use it in the authenticate_user! method. Please help me. I am stuck with this for quiet a long time.

Answer (score 1):

As I answered before, you can override `find_first_by_auth_conditions` method in `User` model. See my previous answer please.

[Is there a solution for Rails Gem Devise to allow a user to have multiple emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285077/is-there-a-solution-for-rails-gem-devise-to-allow-a-user-to-have-multiple-emails/16285486#16285486)

Comment: I read your answer and i could not understand clearly. can you please explain me a bit more. In your answer you have used the find_first_by_auth_conditions method. What i want to know is how can i authenticate user in other controllers as we do using "before_filter :authenticate_user" method?

Comment: As all your controllers inherits from `ApplicationController`, just use this `before_filter`. Method `find_first_by_auth_conditions` specify how devise finds record in database, by default it's smth like `User.where(email: email).first`. If you don't have password field, I can suggest to use `token_authenticatable` option

Comment: In find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions), what is the warden_conditions referring to? and similarly what does conditions = warden_conditions.dup and super(warden_conditions) refer to. Sorry for troubling i am new to this.

Comment: Warden_conditions - are fields used as authentication keys. ex email, login and other